# Search for an expression in Redgate's SQL Search

Tags: ssms, sql-server-tools

I can find word and terms inside stored proc and database, but I can't specifically search for an expression like `WHERE name LIKE '%005%'`.

Is it possible to do that with the Redgate SQL Search plugin for SSMS?

I couldn't find anything that allows me to search for complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to RedGate's [product documentation on SQL Search](https://documentation.red-gate.com/ss/how-to-search) for usage information, and specifically the [wildcards docs](https://documentation.red-gate.com/ss/how-to-search#Howtosearch-Wildcards) which state:

> **Asterisk (*) wildcard**
>
> You can use * as a wildcard to match 0 or more characters, similar to a SQL LIKE clause.
>
> For example, search for 'b*' to find all objects containing words beginning with b.

So in your case you'd want to use `*005*`. Also make sure you have "*Use Wildcards*" checked off in the SQL Search UI as well.

Note that RedGate SQL Search is likely querying the [system catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to satisfy the search that's entered, with a basic UI facing the end user. You could use T-SQL against the system catalog to emulate the same functionality and with the ability to do more complex filtering, for example `sys.procedures` to search for all procedures that contain a given `name` like so:

```
SELECT [name] --, add whatever other columns you need here
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE [name] LIKE '%005%'
```

Please see [Querying the SQL Server System Catalog FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/querying-the-sql-server-system-catalog-faq?view=sql-server-ver15) for more helpful information on using the system catalog.